# ASP.net MVC DropDownListFor or DropDownList with Strongly Typed ViewModel

Tags: asp.net-mvc, drop-down-menu

I'm looking for an example of using DropDownListFor with a strongly typed view model. I have searched extensively and cannot find a good up to date example.

Answer (score 2):

```
<%= Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.Property, 
    new SelectList(your_collection, "key", "code", Model.Property), "") %>
```

"key" and "code" are properties of your Collection objects and the empty "" at the end is an optional label.

Comment: Thanks for answering David. How does m.Property relate to Model.Property?

Comment: As your View is strongly-typed then by doing m => m.Property will only allow you to create the drop down list for a speicifc property of your strongly-typed view. The Model.Property is just the current property value for your object (it could be anything).